# Href attribute not showing for <a> tag when using requests.post

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to download the .csv file that appears on this [page](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm) when I submit the data as

Data for : Security-wise Price volume & Deliverable position data
Symbol : 3INFOTECH
Select Series : All
Period : 24 months

My code is

```
symbol = "3IINFOTECH"
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp"
data = {

    "dataType":"priceVolumeDeliverable",
    "symbol":symbol,
    "segmentLink":"3",
    "symbolCount":"2",
    "series":"ALL",
    "rdPeriod":"groupPeriod",
    "dateRange":"24month"
}

headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'
}
print("fetching for " + symbol)
session = requests.session()
response = requests.post(url, data, headers = headers)
html_content = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

download_link = soup.findAll("span", attrs = {"class":"download-data-link"})[0]
print(download_link.a["href"])
```

Now on inspecting element I see this
[image]

How do I download the csv file? The post request from my code does not show me the href attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the link you have to click the button, so you could use selenium or something equivalent but it is very easy to just parse the data yourself  as all you get back from the post request is the data:

```
symbol = "3IINFOTECH"
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp"
data = {

    "dataType": "priceVolumeDeliverable",
    "symbol": symbol,
    "segmentLink": "3",
    "symbolCount": "2",
    "series": "ALL",
    "rdPeriod": "groupPeriod",
    "dateRange": "24month"
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'
}
print("fetching for " + symbol)
import csv
response = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
html_content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
cols = [th.text for th in soup.select("th")]

rows = ([td.text for td in row.select("td")] for row in soup.select("tr  + tr"))

with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(cols)
    wr.writerows(rows)
```

A snippet of data.csv:

```
Symbol,Series,Date,Prev Close,Open Price,High Price,Low Price,Last Price,Close Price,VWAP,Total Traded Quantity,Turnover in Lacs,No. of Trades,DeliverableQty,% Dly Qt toTraded Qty
3IINFOTECH,EQ,23-May-2014,9.90,10.25,10.70,9.70,10.10,10.10,10.23,"84,99,408",869.20,"16,539","40,35,648",47.48
3IINFOTECH,EQ,26-May-2014,10.10,10.40,10.60,9.10,9.30,9.20,9.97,"59,15,990",589.88,"9,894","27,10,021",45.81
3IINFOTECH,EQ,27-May-2014,9.20,9.20,9.30,8.30,8.60,8.55,8.53,"34,95,072",298.18,"3,600","14,71,141",42.09
3IINFOTECH,EQ,28-May-2014,8.55,8.60,9.40,8.45,9.30,9.15,9.07,"36,09,261",327.27,"3,955","13,92,733",38.59
3IINFOTECH,EQ,29-May-2014,9.15,9.25,9.50,8.80,9.40,9.35,9.28,"30,13,036",279.69,"3,090","15,20,654",50.47
3IINFOTECH,EQ,30-May-2014,9.35,9.35,9.55,8.90,9.00,9.00,9.13,"13,97,140",127.53,"1,992","7,43,964",53.25
```

Comment: the data in the table is incomplete actually. Turns out the entire data was sent in a hidden div which I can parse and extract from. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet, you are not talking about `div id="csvContentDiv"`?

Comment: yes but that appears on a get request to that same link like here `https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=RELIANCE&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=24month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE`. Sorry for the confusion